# Fabric JS background image sizing issue

Tags: javascript, css, canvas, fabricjs

So there's multiple ways to load in a canvas background image but in my code I'm loading it in like this:

```
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('canvas', { backgroundImage: "<?php echo $image; } ?>", }
```

in the tutorial I found (https://www.tutorialspoint.com/how-to-create-a-canvas-with-background-image-using-fabricjs) it shows how to set the canvas height and width like so:

```
canvas.setWidth(document.body.scrollWidth / 2.2);
canvas.setHeight(650);
```

But I need to resize the background image itself not the whole canvas and I cannot find anywhere online describing how to do this.  Logically it should be set when I set the canvas background image initially something like this:

```
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('canvas', { backgroundImage: "<?php echo $image; } ?>", backgroundImageWidth: "50%", backgroundImageHeight: "100%",}
```

but that does not work, and I've tried a couple other things like setBackgroundImageWidth:  or backgroundSize: etc...   just shooting in the dark here.  I can't find any stackoverflow questions describing setting the background image size this way.  Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to specify the dimensions of a background image inside fabricJS' constructor. As you're loading an image from an URL, you have to utilize the Image class' `fromURL()` method to instantiate a fabricJS Image, which you then can use with the `backgroundImage` property.

The fromURL() method accepts a callback function which should take care of the actual resizing of the image. Unfortunately you can't simply alter the width & height as fabricJS locks the aspect ratio internally. Instead you have to calculate the desired width & height as a scale and use the image's `.scaleX` & `.scaleY` properties.

Here's an example:

```js
let canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
document.body.appendChild(canvas);
let canv = new fabric.Canvas(canvas, {
    backgroundColor: 'rgba(230, 230, 230, 1)',
    backgroundImage: fabric.Image.fromURL("https://picsum.photos/id/237/400/300", (img) => {

        img.scaleX = canv.width * 0.5 / img.width;
        img.scaleY = canv.height * 0.5 / img.height;

        canv.backgroundImage = img;
        canv.renderAll();
    })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/5.3.1/fabric.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, just logged in.  But thank you for this!  When nobody answered the other day I logged off and tried to figure it out myself.  I did figure it out, a little different way then this but this would of worked too.  Thank you!